# Interleave two SQL columns into paired array

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to Interleave two SQL columns into paired array.
How do I turn this:

```
id         key      val
---        ---      ---             
1          a        apple
1          b        boy
2          x        xray
2          y        yellow
```

into this:

```
new_id         array    
---        ---             
1          {a,apple},{b,boy}
2          {x,xray},{y,yellow}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is very specific to this case (i.e. 2 items per `id`) so it might not be sufficient but it does work in your case:

```
select 
   id
   , ARRAY[min(kv), max(kv)] 
from 
   (select 
    id
    , ARRAY[key, val] kv from fruit
   ) s 
group by 
  id 
order by 
  id;

┌────┬───────────────────────┐
│ id │         array         │
├────┼───────────────────────┤
│ 1  │ {{a,apple},{b,boy}}   │
│ 2  │ {{x,xray},{y,yellow}} │
└────┴───────────────────────┘
(2 rows)
```